# htaccess configuration directories for subdomains and root domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My folders in my `www` directory as set up as follows:

- `www/forums`
- `www/helpdesk`
- `www/www`

In the base `www` folder (not `www/www`), I have the following set up in my htaccess file to redirect based on subdirectory

```
  # Direct subdomains to appropriate folder in WWW directory
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I also have the following set up for configuring the `index.php` on the main site (`www.example.com`) - this is also in the htaccess file in the `www` directory:

```
  # Rewrite rules
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem I am facing is that I have stuff from `forums.example.com` that I want to embed in `www.example.com` (Vanilla Forums + WordPress plugin) - if I configure this using the admin panels, the iFrame gets blocked because they are different domains.

I found out that when I go to `www.example.com/forums`, I get the same front page as `forums.examples.com` - but all the clean URLs break.

When I look at the `.htaccess` file in the `www/forums` folder, I see the following configuration

```
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What do I need to do to the .htaccess file in the `www` directory so that when I go to `www.example.com/forums`, it works the same as if I went to `forums.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

> ...the following set up in my htaccess file to redirect based on subdirectory
>   `# Direct subdomains to appropriate folder in WWW directory`

*Aside*: That snippet is just a canonical non-www to www redirect. It doesn't "redirect based on subdirectory" nor does it "direct [any] subdomains". (?)

> the iFrame gets blocked because they are different domains.

It sounds as if you need to set an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP response header on `forums.example.com` to allow the content to be "embedded" in `example.com`? Something like the following (using mod_headers) in the `www/forums/.htaccess` file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com"
```

> What do I need to do to the `.htaccess` file in the `www` directory so that when I go to `www.example.com/forums`, it works the same as if I went to `forums.example.com`.

How do "all the clean URLs break"? However, given the HTTP header mentioned above, you shouldn't have to do anything more and still access `forums.example.com` (not the subdirectory).

Incidentally, the fact you can access the subdirectory (that the subdomain points to) is just how your hosting is configured. Normally you should block access to the subdirectory in order to prevent duplicate content issues (and any other issues, such as the linking problem you mention).

Also note, that due to the way mod_rewrite directives are inherited (or *not* in this case). The mod_rewrite directives in the `www/forums/.htaccess` file completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent folder.